# Block all incoming trafic to VBox guest VM, except ESTABLISHED and RELATED

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, virtualbox

I have host machine, which is running Virtualbox and one guest VM. Let's say host have interface br0 with IP `1.2.3.4` and guest have eth0 with IP `1.2.3.5`.

Guest is using `1.2.3.5` as public IP (bridged interface, via br0 on host). I want it to be able to access Internet, but want to completely block all attempts to access it from outside. It is not serving anything, it could be completely blocked out of the Internet, if not the fact that it need to download a thing or two from time to time...

How to do that on the host, without impacting host? **Not on the guest, on the host**. I want host to be accessible from the outside world, from the Internet. But guest should only receive packets that are related to connections established by the guest. No ssh login attempts, nothing initiated from outside (I know, I can use other tools to secure the guest also, like sshd_config on guest, and I use them but I want to use iptables also).

I tried blocking everything related to the guest first and then work my way up to excluding `RELATED` and `ESTABLISHED`, but even if I add DROP rules with 1.2.3.5 as source and destination to all chains on host (`INPUT`, `FORWARD`, `OUTPUT`), I can still ping `1.2.3.5` from outside world. What am I doing wrong? Yes, I added those rules in the beginning of chains (`-I`). iptables behave differently when I am doing it on a host and traffic is destined to the virtual machine/guest? Or is it because I use bridge br0?

So I am not even able to DROP everything coming from and to `1.2.3.5` (IP that is on the guest VM) even though tcpdump on a host shows `1.2.3.5` as source and destination when I run it to intercept ICMP packets, while I ping 1.2.3.5 from outside world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can manipulate traffic going through the bridge, I'm not sure you can do connection tracking (`RELATED`/`ESTABLISHED`).

The place to do it would be the `FORWARD` chain.

What does `sysctl -a|grep -E "bridge-nf-call-ip.*tables"` give you? If you set, for instance, `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` to `1`, and do `iptables -P FORWARD DROP`, the guest should no longer have internet. You can take it from there and see if you can more.

Comment: That sysctl with a grep returned nothing. I had to load `br_netfilter` kernel module (it is CentOS 7). Now I have: `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1`,
`net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1`. But dropping everything on FORWARD chain still does nothing for the guest. It can be pinged from outside world. Don't know if it changes anything, but I am using Vagrant to manage VirtualBox machine. Probably do not change much.

Comment: Ok, there is one thing that I failed to mention and maybe that's why I can not do that. The host itself is a KVM virtual machine. I am using nested virtualization. So there is "master host", on which there is a KVM machine, the one that I call "a host" and then on that KVM machine is VirtualBox "guest".

I guess that it might be too complicated to be worth debugging. I will probably close this question. The "host" is also using bridge on "master host" to access network.

Sorry for failing to mention that.

Comment: I actually have no idea if that influences things. Experimentation would be required.

Comment: So to sum things up, I didn't knew about br_netfilter and in normal circumstances that would probably solve things and I would be able to block traffic via FORWARD chain. In my case it is not working because of complications of my environment that I did not mention in original question. That's why I am marking this answer as a solution.